# Only one select tag is required to POST form

Tags: javascript, html

Title basically says it all.
I have 3 select tags and I want to make it proceedable if any of the selects is filled.

- It can proceed if **one** is filled.
- It can proceed if **two** are filled.
- It can proceed if **three** are filled.
- It cannot proceed if **none** are filled.

Right now it can only proceed if all three are filled because I added "required" attribute in each select. What should I do?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Option 1</td>
    <td>
      <select id="first" name="q4_op1" required>
        <option value="" selected>Select an option</option>
        <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
        <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
        <option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
        <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
        <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
        <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Option 2</td>
    <td>
      <select id="second" name="q4_op2" required>
        <option value="" selected>Select an option</option>
        <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
        <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
        <option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
        <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
        <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
        <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Option 3</td>
    <td>
      <select id="terceiro" name="q4_op3" required>
        <option value="" selected>Select an option</option>
        <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
        <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
        <option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
        <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
        <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
        <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You'll need to write some JavaScript in order to do this. You can't use the `required` attribute on a HTML `<select>` to accomplish this. Have you ever done JS before? Give it a stab and edit your question when you get stuck!

Comment: Yes I've used JS! The problem is I don't know how to really do it...

Comment: You need to edit your question and put the [mcve] in it, not on a third party site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is as follows:

```
// here we declare the function, and pass in the 'event' argument,
// this is the Event Object passed automagically from
// EventTarget.addEventListener(), later. We're using Arrow function
// syntax since we don't need to reference 'this':
const submissionCheck = (event) => {

  // here we use the preventDefault() method of the Event Object
  // in order to prevent the <button> automatically submitting
  // the form:
  event.preventDefault();

  // here we retrieve the relevant <form> within which the
  // submit button is placed, first we access the 'target'
  // property of the Event Object to retrieve the element on
  // which this function is bound (the <button> in this example)
  // and from there we navigate to the 'form' property of that
  // element:
  const form = event.target.form;

  // here we use Element.querySelector() to look for:
  // an <option> element found within a <select> element,
  // which does not have a 'value' attribute with an empty
  // attribute-value and we check that the <option> is checked
  // (which applies to <option> elements that are selected/activated,
  // because Element.querySelector() returns either the first
  // element matching the selector (if any exist) or null (if no
  // element exists) we then test that the result is not-equal to null:
  if (form.querySelector('select option:not([value=""]):checked') !== null) {
    // So, if an <option> exists with a non-empty value attribute-value
    // which is also checked/selected, we then submit the <form>:
    form.submit();
  }
}

// here we find the <button> element in the document, and use
// EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the submissionCheck()
// function (note the deliberate lack of parentheses) as the
// 'click' event-handler:
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', submissionCheck);
```

```js
const submissionCheck = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const form = event.target.form;
  if (form.querySelector('select option:not([value=""]):checked') !== null) {
    form.submit();
  }
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', submissionCheck);
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <table>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <!-- I also added <label> elements so that clicking the
             relevant text activates and focuses the <select>
             element: -->
        <td><label for="first">Option 1</label></td>
        <td>
          <select id="first" name="q4_op1">
            <option value="" selected>Select an option</option>
            <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
            <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
            <option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
            <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
            <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
            <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><label for="second">Option 2</label></td>
        <td>
          <select id="second" name="q4_op2">
            <option value="" selected>Select an option</option>
            <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
            <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
            <option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
            <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
            <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
            <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><label for="terceiro">Option 3</label></td>
        <td>
          <select id="terceiro" name="q4_op3">
            <option value="" selected>Select an option</option>
            <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
            <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
            <option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
            <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
            <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
            <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4dgkuxvq/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute selectors (`attribute="AttributeValue"]`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).
  - [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked).
  - [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).
- HTML:

  - [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).
- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
  - [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).
  - [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`HTMLFormElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement).
  - [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var any = (
    document.getElementById('first').selectedIndex ||
    document.getElementById('second').selectedIndex ||
    document.getElementById('terceiro').selectedIndex
)

if (any !== 0) {
    // proceed
}
```

The `||` [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) will do exaclty what you want.
Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Azev/wocjf14e/).

Comment: Can I use it inside the select like "onchange="function name""?

Comment: @MiguelLeitão You can, but is not appropriate. You should nox mix HTML code and JavaScript.

Comment: Please take the time to explain your code in order that others can understand it and amend it to their needs. Yes, I can understand it, but the OP and future visitors searching for answers to similar problems might not, and without explanation how should they learn?

Comment: I tried it and it allowed me to proceed even if none of the options were selected :(
Literally implemented it into my original code.

Comment: @MiguelLeitão Please, share your code here: https://jsfiddle.net. Click "save" when done and share the URL with us

Comment: Can't I create like a div and make it required or that doen't work?

Comment: Once I click on the button, it goes to another page but I want to only make it possible only if the first, second and fourth questions are filled which.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Option 1</td>
            <td>
                <select id="first" name="q4_op1">
                    <option value="" selected>Select an option</option>
                    <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
                    <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
                    <option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
                    <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
                    <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
                    <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Option 2</td>
            <td>
                <select id="second" name="q4_op2">
                    <option value="" selected>Select an option</option>
                    <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
                    <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
                    <option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
                    <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
                    <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
                    <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
                  </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Opção 3</td>
            <td>
                <select id="terceiro" name="q4_op3">
                    <option value="" selected>Select an option</option>
                    <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
                    <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
                    <option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
                    <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
                    <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
                    <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
                  </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Save data!" />
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {    
    var any = (
        document.getElementById('first').selectedIndex ||
        document.getElementById('second').selectedIndex ||
        document.getElementById('terceiro').selectedIndex
    )

    if (any !== 0) {
        return true
    }

    alert('Please select at least one option.');
    return false
})
</script>
```

Here's what I changed:

- added a `<form>` with an ID of `myForm`
- added a `input` that users can click to submit `myForm`
- wrote a JavaScript function that gets called every time the user submits the form
- this function

  - checks to see if any of the 3 fields were filled out
  - if at least one was filled out the form is allowed to submit
  - if no fields are filled out the form submission gets cancelled and we tell the user they must fill at least one field

Comment: Please do not aswer with another user answer (copy/paste). If you are going to answer, create **your OWN** answer.

Comment: Plagiarism. You just copy and paste my answer bellow.